# Angular 2 Pipe Doesn't Return Data to *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

Hello i am confused as to why this is happening but I have an Angular2 stock market app, and I am trying to filter my symbols through a Pipe to return an object of price data..Here's the Problem: I can see the data fetching correctly when i console.log it, but for some reason I can't get it passed into my *ngFor method... Appreciate any support!

StockDataFiler.ts

```
  transform(value, args) {
    this.markit.getPriceInfo(value).subscribe(
      data => {
        value = data;
        return value;
        //NOTE: console.log(value) shows the data in my console 
      },
      err => {
          console.log(err);
      },
      () => console.log('Stock Fetch Complete')
    );
  }
```

home.html

```
  <div *ngFor="let stock of watchlist | async">
    <div *ngFor="let data of stock.symbol | StockDataFilter">
      <h1>{{data}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Seems that you're trying to implement something like your own async pipe. Would be an overkill, instead try something like: ...<div *ngFor="let data of markit.getPriceInfo(stock.symbol) | async"> ....

Comment: Any errors? What is code for stockdataflter?

Comment: Have you tried making your pipe impure? just add pure: false inside of your @Pipe metadata.

Comment: No errors, and i tried making it impure but it just broke in an infinite loop